# Detect when animation ends (Android studio)

Tags: java, android

I set a fade-out animation for a textView like this:

`textView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(200);`

I need some other code to execute once the animation has finished, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

u should user `**AnimatorListerAdapter**` is abstract class that implement **`AnimatorListener`** that base class for animation `**AnimatorListerAdapter**` has variant of method for start , pause, complete for animation you can use what u need according to your needs

example below:

```java
textView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(200).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        //do your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: should have an explaination to the OP - (i.e. you're missing `setListener` and new `AnimatorListerAdapter`)

Comment: i think you can see package ** `android.animation` **  note that `AnimatorListerAdapter` is abstract class that implement `AnimatorListener` that base class for animation AnimatorListerAdapter  has variant of method for start , pause, complete for animation you can use what u need according to your needs

Comment: Was Reviewing: Updated the answer with a brief explanation (this answer was flagged as being too short/low quality). You explanation should be included in the answer for others to know this is not a low quality answer